# Why hash code computed using division method instead of universal hashing method?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I find the following code for compute [hashcode](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs):

```
int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
int index = hashCode % buckets.Length;
```

Why engineers didn't choose a universal hashing method:

```
int index = [(ak + b) mod p)mod buckets.Length]
```

where `a,b` are random numbers between `0...p-1` (p is prime) ?

Comment: Hard to say why they did it. Maybe they thought the faster algorithm still provided sufficient distribution. Hard to say without knowing the distribution of `comparer.GetHashCode(key)`.

Comment: This question might be more relevant in a meta forum.

Comment: I thought is was good practice to override the GetHasCode method with your own unique method for generating a hashcode usually involving the contents of the object.

Comment: I think that the main problem is that already proved that universal hashing method works good for any key, instead of division method. So i also dont know why engineers use division method

Comment: Because they use the high bit for something else. Take a look at `Entry` struct definition - `public int hashCode;    // Lower 31 bits of hash code, -1 if unused`

Comment: @IvanStoev Why they don't use randomness?

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko Actually this is the responsibility of the hash code provider (`IEqualityComparer<T>`), the dictionary is just a consumer.

Comment: That "universal hashing method" is only applicable to combine *two* hash codes into a single one.  The Dictionary code is a simple way to convert the hash code to a positive integer that's suitable to index the bucket array.  The 32nd bit does not contribute to making it better distributed.

Answer (score 2):

A complete answer to the question would require consulting with the individual(s) who wrote that code. So I don't think you're going to get a complete answer.

That said:

1. The "universal hashing method", as you call it, is hardly the only possible implementation of a good hash code. People implement hash code computations in a variety of ways for a variety of reasons.

More important though…

2. The computation to which you refer *is not actually computing a hash code*. The variable name is a bit misleading, because while the value is based on the hash code of the item in question, it's really an implementation detail of the class's internal hash table. By sacrificing the highest bit from the *actual* hash code, the `Entry` value for the hash table can be flagged as unused using that bit. Masking the bit off as opposed to, for example, just special-casing an element with a hash code value of `-1`, preserves the distribution qualities of the original hash code implementation (which is determined outside the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class).

In other words, the code you're asking about is simply how the author of that code implemented a particular optimization, in which they decreased the size of the `Entry` value by storing a flag they needed for some other purpose — i.e. the purpose of indicating whether a particular table `Entry` is used or not — in the same 32-bit value where part of the element's hash code is stored.

Storing the hash code in the `Entry` value is in turn also an optimization. Since the `Entry` value includes the `TKey key` value for the element, the implementation *could* in fact just have always called the `key.GetHashCode()` method to get the hash code. This is a trade-off in acknowledging that the `GetHashCode()` method is not always optimized itself (indeed, most implementations, including .NET's implementation for the `System.String` class, always recompute the hash code from scratch), and so the choice was (apparently) made to cache the hash code value within the `Entry` value, rather than asking the `TKey` value to recompute it every time it's needed.

Don't confuse the caching and subsequent usage of some *other* object's hash code implementation with an actual hash code implementation. The latter is not what's going on in the code you're asking about, the former is.